# How do I terminate android app programmatically when home button pressed?

Tags: android, exit, terminate

I am trying to build in code to terminate an app programmatically when the home button is pressed.  I tried the following:

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
    this.finish();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

but it still doesn't work.   the program is still running in the background.  any ideas?

Comment: "terminate an app programmatically when the home button is pressed" -- why? "the program is still running in the background" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: From the docs: "Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill." This means that even if the call does not fail (no exception) there may be no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind to use **brute killing** ? [asynchronous and immediately]

```
public void onStop()
     {
     AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable(){public void run()
              {
              android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
              }});
     }
```

- **Remember:** Android wasn't designed to kill the app over HOME BUTTON PRESS

... you decide

Answer (score -2):

Create the following constant in your class:

```
public static final int KEYCODE_HOME
```

Override onAttachedToWindow method:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

And set a listener for the home button being pressed:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //This will close the current activity
       finish();
    }
});
```

Take a look at this:
[Intercept Home Key](http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please copy the contents of that link to create a complete, proper answer.